# TLS certificate works in Firefox but doesn't in Chrome

Tags: ssl, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have a microservices written with C# (ASP.NET Core 2.2) and I use nginx ingress as an API Gateway. I have a handshake exception on mobile app when trying to use a real device (Android), but everything is OK when I use the iOS emulator. Besides, I tried to use the API from browsers, and I had success in Firefox and Safari, but Chrome shows the "Not secured connection". I would really appreciate it if you could help me resolving the issue.

On the google cloud I have a secret for TLS with crt and key.

All services use the PFX file (ASP.NET Core, Kestrel), generated with crt and key. This configuration works, I'm 100% sure, since I used a docker-compose before and didn't face this issue. The certificate is valid. That's why I'm thinking that it might be something related to ingress...

Ingress configuration:

```
...
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: my-tls
    hosts:
    - api.whatever.com
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing known about the certificate, the servers configuration, any configuration differences between the browsers (like use of proxy) and the exact error message from Chrome (including the details from "Advanced" information). Because of this lack of information the question can not be answered.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I updated the question. Regarding the browsers, no I don't use the proxy, and I don't have any special settings for Chrome. Anyway, that's just an example, cause I mostly need it for a mobile application, which is written with Flutter, and I have the handshake exception only on Android.